# Does Python sorted() actually CHANGE the list being sorted?

Tags: python, sorting

```
rat_nreads = sorted([(self.markers2lens[m],n) for m,n in self.markers2nreads.items()],key = lambda x: x[1])
rat_nreads, removed = [], []
```

I saw this code and was really confused; what is the point of assigning `rat_nreads` to a sorted list if it's going to be assigned to an empty list right after? Does the first line actually change `self.markers2nreads.items()` in any way?

Comment: If you want in-place sorting, use `<list>.sort()`

Comment: [Sorting How To](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: Did you try the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted? *Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable.* that was the very first line

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently reading code from a piece of code used for finding the composition of microbes (MetaPhlan2) and I was really confused when I saw the code I posted.

Answer (score 6):

No, `sorted` creates a new list.

So the code you posted doesn't make sense.

> Does the first line actually change `self.markers2nreads.items()` in any way?

It cannot change, because you have a list comprehension which uses it.

Notes:

- it doesn't make sense to pass a list to `sorted`. `sorted(((self.markers2lens[m],n) for m,n in self.markers2nreads.items()),key = lambda x: x[1])` is more efficient -- a generator is used, no temporary list.
- you should use `dict.iteritems()`, because `dict.items()` also creates a unneeded list.

To sort the list in place, this is needed:

```
_list = [(self.markers2lens[m], n) for m, n in self.markers2nreads.iteritems()]
_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: Ok, thanks so much! I thought I was going crazy. wow i love stackoverflow

Answer (score -1):

The items remain in the same place in memory but a new list is created:

```python
a = [1, 0, 2]
a1 = id(a[0])

b = sorted(a)
b1 = id(b[1])

print a1 == b1
>>>True
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: The memory address stays the same for the item '1', even after sorting. That was my point

Comment: Well obviously, and thats not the point! a1==b1 because they have the same memory address, id(a[0]) or id(b[1]) is the memory address of the item '1' in list a and list b, respectively

Comment: The items haven't changed only the list wrapping the items in memory, i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79960/discussion-between-kezzos-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711387/list-item-keeps-same-memory-address-following-sort-copy/30711554#30711554