# List item keeps same memory address following sort/copy

Tags: python, list

Ive recently become confused about how lists work internally. This code tracks the memory address of the item '1' in these lists following some operations:

```python
a = [1, 0, 2]
b = sorted(a)
c = b[:]

print id(a[0])  
print id(b[1])  # Same memory address
print id(c[1])  # Same memory address
```

The address stays the same in the three lists. How do all the lists contain the same item '1'?

Comment: And they are all the same as `print id(1)`.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @kezzos, he mans `id(1) == id(a[0])`

Comment: Yea, I was confused how different lists point to the same item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally (CPython) the list object stores references to the Python objects it contains. Therefore adding the contents of one list to another won't create new objects. It'll only increment the reference count.

Comment: So creating a new list basically wraps the int objects which already exist

Comment: You could say so. But it holds for every kind of object. The behavior Łukasz pointed out is just a coincidence with your example. [Objects, values and types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) could be interesting for you as well.

Answer (score 4):

Python caches small integers internally (up to 256).

```
a = 1
b = 1
assert a is b

c = 257
d = 257
assert c is d  # raises AssertionError
```

Comment: Thanks, was looking for what this was. Do you have a source?

Comment: @Scironic
Found in the Python documentation, 7.2.1, "[Plain Integer Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html)":

The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behaviour of Python in this case is undefined. :-)

Comment: Should the first assert in your example be `assert a is b`?

Comment: Yep, my bad, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

To add on top of @LukaszR. answer.

While small integers share the same id, copied lists do not.

So:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> c = a
>>> id(a[0]) == id(b[0])
True
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
>>> id(c) == id(a)
True
```

Comment: Which makes sense because the new list object has its own identity, irrespective of what is contains?

Comment: In short, yes. A list is an object on it's own which holds references to other objects. So making a copy makes a new list, but keeps the references (otherwise it wouldn't be a copy).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a=5
>>> id(a)
13897976 #newly created object id
>>> b = 5
```

This time python finds for 5 integer object, if it finds 5 just it tags another name to 5(above it tags for b).

```
>>> id(b)
13897976 # existing 5 integer object id

>>> list1= [25, 5, 0, 'python']
```

Same happens when creating list when you are assigning objects to list, it searches for object in memory if python finds object it just tags list index to that object. if not it will create new memory for that object

```
>>> list1[1]
5
>>> id(list1[1])
13897976 # existing 5 integer object id
>>> p= 'python'
>>> id(p)
139673134424000
>>> id(list1[3])
139673134424000
```

Same thing happen for dictionary's functions, and in your code.
more information [click](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)