# Finding a max from a set of sub keys in dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max, min

I have a list that looks like this (it's Enron data, and therefore publicly available, so pretty sure I'm not breaking any rules here):

```
{
   'METTS MARK':{
      'salary':365788,
      'to_messages':807,
      'deferral_payments':'NaN',
      'total_payments':1061827,
      'loan_advances':'NaN',
      'bonus':600000,
      'email_address':'mark.metts@enron.com',
      'restricted_stock_deferred':'NaN',
      'deferred_income':'NaN',
      'total_stock_value':585062,
      'expenses':94299,
      'from_poi_to_this_person':38,
      'exercised_stock_options':'NaN',
      'from_messages':29,
      'other':1740,
      'from_this_person_to_poi':1,
      'poi':False,
      'long_term_incentive':'NaN',
      'shared_receipt_with_poi':702,
      'restricted_stock':585062,
      'director_fees':'NaN'
   },
   'BAXTER JOHN C':{
      'salary':267102,
      'to_messages':'NaN',
      'deferral_payments':1295738,
      'total_payments':5634343,
      'loan_advances':'NaN',
      'bonus':1200000,
      'email_address':'NaN',
      'restricted_stock_deferred':'NaN',
      'deferred_income':-1386055,
      'total_stock_value':10623258,
      'expenses':11200,
      'from_poi_to_this_person':'NaN',
      'exercised_stock_options':6680544,
      'from_messages':'NaN',
      'other':2660303,
      'from_this_person_to_poi':'NaN',
      'poi':False,
      'long_term_incentive':1586055,
      'shared_receipt_with_poi':'NaN',
      'restricted_stock':3942714,
      'director_fees':'NaN'
   },
   'ELLIOTT STEVEN':{
      'salary':170941,
      'to_messages':'NaN',
      'deferral_payments':'NaN',
      'total_payments':211725,
      'loan_advances':'NaN',
      'bonus':350000,
      'email_address':'steven.elliott@enron.com',
      'restricted_stock_deferred':'NaN',
      'deferred_income':-400729,
      'total_stock_value':6678735,
      'expenses':78552,
      'from_poi_to_this_person':'NaN',
      'exercised_stock_options':4890344,
      'from_messages':'NaN',
      'other':12961,
      'from_this_person_to_poi':'NaN',
      'poi':False,
      'long_term_incentive':'NaN',
      'shared_receipt_with_poi':'NaN',
      'restricted_stock':1788391,
      'director_fees':'NaN'
   }
}
```

I'm trying to make a list of all `exercised_stock_options` values, and then I want to find the non `NaN` values and perform a max/min.

I did this but I get an incorrect answer, and I'm not sure why:

```
eso = []
for k,v in data_dict.items():
    # name.append[str(k)]
    eso.append(v['exercised_stock_options'])

# Remove NaN values in list
eso = [x for x in eso if str(x) != 'NaN']

print(eso)

sorted(eso)
print(eso[0])
print(eso[-1])
```

But then I saw this answer and it's correct, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong?

```
stock = []
for i in data_dict:
    if (data_dict[i]["exercised_stock_options"]=='NaN'):
        pass
    else:
        stock.append(float(data_dict[i]["exercised_stock_options"]))

ma = max(stock)
mi = min(stock)

print ("Exercised stock options maximum: ", ma, " minimum: ", mi)
```

Comment: `sorted` doesn't change the list, it simply returns a sorted version of it.  Replace `sorted(eso)` with `eso.sort()`, which will destructively sort `eso`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python sorted() actually CHANGE the list being sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706746/does-python-sorted-actually-change-the-list-being-sorted)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \`sorted(list)\` vs \`list.sort()\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort)

Comment: Alternatively `eso = sorted(eso)`

Comment: Another point, your list is string whereas the solution you showed is casting the values to float. Not sure if sorting like this will affect the result.

Comment: @Michael The `sort` method is preferred (for efficiency) in cases where the original list order isn't needed, since it avoids an unnecessary copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the values are sorted as strings, however, you want to sort them as numbers. This is why implicit type casting (with `float` function) is used in the second case.

You may want to change line `eso.append(v['exercised_stock_options'])` to `eso.append(float(v['exercised_stock_options']))`. But you should get rid of 'NaN' values first.